# Enable own metrics when all other are disabled

Tags: spring-micrometer

I would like to turn off all metrics except my own metrics.
I used the property for that. However, my own metrics were then also switched off.

```
management.metrics.enable.all=false
```

How can I turn it back on?

I've tried the following, unfortunately it doesn't work

```
management.metrics.enable.all=false
management.metrics.enable.my=true
Metrics.gauge( "my.metric.name", List.of("tag1","tag2"), value );
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different way of allowing only yours metrics is to use a *deny* filter and only allow your custom metric to pass through. It will not disable other metrics but just denying them from being pushed or pulled.

Spring-Boot example:

```
@Configuration
public class MetricRegistryConfig {
  @Bean
  public MeterRegistryCustomizer<MeterRegistry> metricsRegistryConfig() {
    return registry -> registry.config()
        .meterFilter(MeterFilter
            .deny(id -> !"my.metric.name".equals(id.getName())));
  }
}
```